# Уведомления в Asp.net от WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net-web-api

Есть ситуация: фронт-энд делает запрос на бэк.

При запросе на бэке должны отработать 10 долгоиграющих метода, но клиенту ответ нужно вернуть как можно быстрее, а в будущем порциями выдавать результаты каждого метода.

Подскажите, как можно решить такую задачу?

В данный момент каждый метод просто запускается в Task.Run, но ведь это плохой способ.
**UPDATE:**
Методы в Task.Run пишут результат в БД.
Фронт каждые 10сек делает запрос на бэк до тех пор, пока бэк не вернёт результаты всех 10 методов.

Comment: Можете добавить wizard, спрашивать пользователя шаг за шагом и выдавать информацию небольшими порциями до тех пор, пока он не потребует что-то конкретное.

Comment: Похоже, здесь оптимально будет [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) —  он позволит «достучаться» с сервера (WebAPI) к клиенту (JavaScript).

Comment: О SignalR были мысли. Но разве его можно использовать в связке "Сначала клиент сделал запрос к asp.net web api и ему сразу вернули ответ, а далее SignalR периодически шлёт push'и"?

Comment: @NailTabeyev Да, не вижу проблем: сначала сразу отвечаем что-то вроде «запрос принят», далее, по ходу выполнения тасков, пушим уведомления в JavaScript, откуда, в свою очередь, модифицируем html-страницы (уведомляем пользователя о прогрессе выполнения задач).

Comment: @NailTabeyev по-поводу вашего апдейта: SignalR как раз позволит избежать периодического опроса сервера. Решение с пушем представляется более элегантным и интересным.